# Does *meditari* mean "measure"?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

Does *meditari* have a meaning like "measure"?

Using Google (I don't know which dictionary it's quoting), I see ...

[image]

---

However I don't think I'm seeing that in a Latin dictionary, e.g. [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmeditor) or even [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meditor#Latin).

Comment: No, Latin meditor was primarily used in the sense of “deliberare, considerare” (TLL).

Comment: Well, it's not too far a stretch to render it as "weigh", as in deliberating by weighing your options.

Comment: @NRitH of course, but 'weigh' - or rather 'measure' (see the post above) - should *not* be listed as the primary sense though.